# F# Fsharp.compiler.service Fsharp.Data.TypeProvider error

Tags: f#, fsharp.data.typeproviders

The following piece of F# code compile perfectly well with F# 3.0 fsc.exe 
but fails to execute. In interactive Mode (fsi.exe) everything works correctly.

I get errror message.

> "Referenced assembly
>   'C:_src_\compilation_sql\FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll' has assembly
>   level attribute
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute'
>   but no public type provider classes were found" at execution time.

Why ?

### The idea :

The program write in a `current.fs` file a piece of code and call `Fsharp.compiler.service` to compile the script into a DLL assembly

### Problem : the sequence :

> let errors1, exitCode1 = scs.Compile([|
>   "fsc";"-r:System.Core.dll";"-r:System.Collections.Immutable.dll";"-r:System.Reflection.Metadata.dll";"-r:FSharp.Compiler.dll";"-r:FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.dll";"-r:System.Data.Linq.dll";"-r:FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll";"-r:FSharp.Compiler.Service.dll"
>   ;"-r:FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"; "-o"; fn3; "-a"; fn2 |])

failed when it is executed from a compiled version of the program.

I compiled the code with the command line  :

> fsc.exe -r:System.Core.dll -r:System.Collections.Immutable.dll
>   -r:System.Reflection.Metadata.dll -r:FSharp.Compiler.dll -r:FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.dll -r:System.Data.Linq.dll -r:FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll -r:FSharp.Compiler.Service.dll compilation_sql.fs

I execute the compiled program very simply :

```
compilation_sql.exe
```

### Source code :

```
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory (__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__) 
printfn "repertoire d execution : %s" __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__

#if INTERACTIVE
#r "System.Data.Linq.dll"
#r "FSharp.Compiler.dll"
#r "FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.dll"
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"
#r "FSharp.Compiler.Service.dll"
#r "System.Collections.Immutable.dll"
#r "System.Reflection.Metadata.dll"
#endif

open System
open System.IO
open System.Collections.Immutable
open System.Reflection.Metadata
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.SimpleSourceCodeServices
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
open System.Data.Linq.SqlClient




// let fn = Path.GetTempFileName()
let fn = sprintf "%s\\current.fs" __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ 
printfn "Fichier à Compiler %s" fn
let fn2 = Path.ChangeExtension(fn, ".fs")
let fn3 = Path.ChangeExtension(fn, ".dll")

let script = """
#if INTERACTIVE
#r "System.Data.dll"
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"
#r "System.Data.Linq.dll"
#else
namespace ODDO
#endif
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
open System.Data.Linq.SqlClient

module SQL=
 [<Literal>]
 let sourceConnectionString = @"Data Source=ZDATLMDL6\Z_MUT_3; Initial Catalog=DB_FXO; Integrated Security=True;"


 type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<sourceConnectionString>

 let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
 // Enable the logging of database activity to the console.
 db.DataContext.Log <- System.Console.Out

 let query1 =
    query {
                                 for row in db.COMPTEUR do
                                 select row
    }

 let display (res : System.Linq.IQueryable<dbSchema.ServiceTypes.COMPTEUR>) =
     printfn "Resultat :"        
     res |> Seq.iter (fun row -> printfn "%d %s %s " row.ID row.CODE row.LIBELLE )
     printfn "Fin de table"
     ()
"""
File.WriteAllText(fn2, script)
let scs = SimpleSourceCodeServices()
//let errors1, exitCode1 = scs.Compile([| "fsc";"-r:System.Core.dll";"-r:FSharp.Compiler.dll";"-r:FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.dll";"-r:System.Data.Linq.dll";"-r:FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll";"-r:FSharp.Compiler.Service.dll"; "-o"; fn3; "-a"; fn2 |])
let errors1, exitCode1 = scs.Compile([| "fsc";"-r:System.Core.dll";"-r:System.Collections.Immutable.dll";"-r:System.Reflection.Metadata.dll";"-r:FSharp.Compiler.dll";"-r:FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.dll";"-r:System.Data.Linq.dll";"-r:FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll";"-r:FSharp.Compiler.Service.dll" ;"-r:FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"; "-o"; fn3; "-a"; fn2 |])

printfn "Nombre erreurs compilation : %d" errors1.Length 

for i in 0..errors1.Length - 1 do
   let mutable werror = Array.get errors1 i
 //  printfn "%s %d %s %d " werror.get_FileName() werror.get_ErrorNumber() werror.get_Message() werror.get_StartLine()
   printfn "Fichier : %s ErrorNumber : %d Message :%s" werror.FileName werror.ErrorNumber werror.Message
```

I am new to F# and probably don't know enough about assembly but this fools me.
can any one give any hint ?

Comment: Try unblocking the downloaded DLL file. Right-click it, go into the properties and click the "Unblock" button (pre Windows 10) or check the "Unblock" checkbox (Windows 10). There is also the `Unblock-File` PowerShell cmdlet if you're familiar with it. Then it should work.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Unfortunately The file do not show in its properties window any "unblock" button. I also used System tools to look for locked files but to no avail. I have an Administrator login and work on a windows 7 version. The fact is that  the program fails to execute when compiled with fsc.exe but runs perfectly in fsi.exe. perhaps The DLL is blocked at execution time and this prevent The compiler service from accessing it. I don't know.